# Prevent __init__ from using paramers from older object throug the heap

Tags: python, memory, constructor, python-3.6, heap-memory

Here I have some python code.
A loop creates an object with non-binding paramerters.

The **first time** everything works normally.

In the **second run**, however, the **attribute of the last object** created is **used as the parameter**.

This works with the dictionary because it is **stored in the heap**.

How do I make sure that if **no parameters are specified**, they are **not read from the heap**?

```
class ClassXY:
    def __init__(self, variables={}):
        print(variables)
        self.variables = variables
        self.variables["key"] = "xyz"

for i in range(3):
    ClassXY()
```

The output:

```
{}
{'key': 'xyz'}
{'key': 'xyz'}
```

The output I want:

```
{}
{}
{}
```

Thank you :D

Comment: "The heap" is not a useful concept in Python.

Comment: apparently not here

Comment: Side-note: For this particular case of the mutable default argument, a reasonable solution is to *keep* the mutable default, but change the assignment to `self.variables = variables.copy()`. Copying before storing to the instance attribute prevents mutation of the default argument, and also (partially) decouples you from any caller provided argument, so your changes don't mutate their copy of the `dict` and vice versa. And it's simpler (possibly faster) code that using `None` as the default, testing for it, and replacing `None` with a new `{}` if found.

Comment: Nice, it works fine.